# Expression of type 'Lodgx.Classes.Models.Timespan' is not queryable

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Here I am again with a question regarding this XML I'm parsing. I'm trying to get the Element TimeSpan and it's attributes. This is the code I'm using

```
Dim time As Timespan = From el In _xDoc.Elements(_ns + "TimesSpan").Select(Function(e) New Timespan With { _
                                                                .Duration = e.Attribute("Duration"), _
                                                                .StartDate = e.Attribute("Start"), _
                                                                .EndDate = e.Attribute("End")}).FirstOrDefault()
```

But that gives me the error

> Expression of type 'Lodgx.Classes.Models.Timespan' is not queryable.
>   Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace
>   import for the LINQ provider.

**EDIT**

I changed my code to look like this:

```
Dim time = From el As XElement In _xDoc.Elements(_ns + "TimeSpan")
                       Select New Timespan With { _
                           .Duration = el.Attribute("Duration").Value, _
                           .StartDate = el.Attribute("Start").Value, _
                           .EndDate = el.Attribute("End").Value}

Return time.First()
```

Now when I run it I get a message > **Sequence contains no elements** on the line Return **time.First()**

**EDIT #2**

_xDoc is an XDocument which loads the XML string from the web service call

```
Dim _xDoc = XDocument.Load(str)
```

I've checked the value of **str** and it's what I'm expecting

@MarcinJuraszek: Here's a small sample of the XML (It's a huge file so I'll just post a little which includes the Element TimeSpan, which I'm trying to get the attribute values from)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" TimeStamp="2013-12-30T18:49:36" Version="1.14.1">
  <Success xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" />
<RoomStay xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07">
    <Guarantee>
      <DepositsAccepted>
        <PaymentCard CardType="AMERICAN EXPRESS" CardCode="AX" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="MASTERCARD" CardCode="CA" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="DINERS CLUB CARD" CardCode="DC" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="DISCOVER CARD" CardCode="DS" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="MASTER CARD" CardCode="IK" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="JCB CREDIT CARD" CardCode="JC" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="VISA" CardCode="VI" />
      </DepositsAccepted>
      <GuaranteesAccepted>
        <PaymentCard CardType="AMERICAN EXPRESS" CardCode="AX" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="MASTERCARD" CardCode="CA" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="DINERS CLUB CARD" CardCode="DC" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="DISCOVER CARD" CardCode="DS" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="MASTER CARD" CardCode="IK" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="JCB CREDIT CARD" CardCode="JC" />
        <PaymentCard CardType="VISA" CardCode="VI" />
        <Text>/GC-              COMPANY NAME AND ADDRESS</Text>
        <Text>/GAGT             GUARANTEE TO AGENCY TIDS/IATA NUMBER</Text>
        <Text>/GDPST            DEPOSIT WILL BE SENT</Text>
        <Text>/GDPST...         IMMEDIATE DEPOSIT TYPE OR FORM</Text>
      </GuaranteesAccepted>
    </Guarantee>
    <TimeSpan Duration="0005" Start="01-14" End="01-15" />
</RoomStay>
  </HotelPropertyDescriptionRS>
```

Comment: What's in `_xDoc`? Please provide a sample.

Comment: OK, you have to show the XML your parsing.

Comment: If you can, please provide a full/valid XML (only with nodes relevant to your code, 1-2, no need for all, but with all tags intact), so that we can paste it (and the code) into a new project and reproduce your problem with ease.

Comment: @Neolisk I updated the XML like you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because TimeSpan element is not a direct descendant of the root, you need to be using `_xDoc.Descendants` instead of `_xDoc.Elements` or specify the full path (you can use *XPath*).

As a side note, be careful with naming your classes, there is already a class in .NET called [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which does not have those properties.

Also, you forgot to include a namespace declaration:

```
Dim _ns As XNamespace =
  XNamespace.Get("http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07")
```

Comment: Thanks @Neolisk that solved the problem. Thanks for taking the time (on this question and my 2 others) for walking me through it and making me learn it instead of just handing me a solution.

Comment: @PsychoCoder: My pleasure to help you! You can further award answers by upvoting them. I am seeing many answers to your questions with no upvotes. You have earned enough reputation by now, so please consider upvoting all or some that you find particularly useful. Thank you.